# jquery radio button change event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display some form when the specific radio button is checked and to hide it when user selects other radio button

```
<div class="col-sm-6" id="addresses">
  <input type="radio" name="deco_request[address]" value="value[&quot;id&quot;]"> Some address<br>
  <input type="radio" name="deco_request[address]" value="other" id="other-address"> Other Address<br>
</div>
```

js code:

```
$("#other-address").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#other-address").is(':checked')) {
    return $("#new-address").show();
  } else {
    return $("#new-address").hide();
  }
});
```

from what I see the change event is not firing up, I also tried click event but didn't have any success with it too, also I noticed when I check the radio button no checked attributes is added but .is(':checked') returns true

Comment: Your code, in terms of the event being called is working, I tried it in jsfiddle adding some alert to the if - else. Make sure jQuery is being added to the code

Comment: jquery is added, I have some other jquery code on this page which works ok

Comment: The event is being called, you can check it adding an alert()

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `return` and use `prop` to check

PS: your check syntax is valid but sometimes is not working properly

```
$("#other-address").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#other-address").prop("checked", true)) {
     $("#new-address").show();
  } else {
     $("#new-address").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
$("input[name='deco_request[address]']").change(function() {
  $("#new-address").toggle();
});
```

```js
$("input[name='deco_request[address]']").change(function() {
  $("#new-address").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" id="addresses">
  <input type="radio" name="deco_request[address]" value="value[&quot;id&quot;]"> Some address<br>
  <input type="radio" name="deco_request[address]" value="other" id="other-address"> Other Address<br>
</div>

<div id="new-address">Address</div>
```

Comment: this works for two inputs, but in my case the inputs will be generated dynamically and in some cases it can be only one or a lot of them

Comment: so how you can define with which is hide which is show

Comment: it should be shown only when other-address is checked, anyway, you solution must work if I will check if the other-address is checked inside change event, but unfortunately it's not working for me, I just let the change event and put a console.log in it but it didn't show

Answer (score 0):

change this way

```
$("#addresses input").on("change", function() {
  if ($("#other-address").is(':checked')) {
    return $("#new-address").show();
  } else {
    return $("#new-address").hide();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6d0zydjj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can do your issue solved

```
$('.radio').change(function(){
        if ($("#other-address").is(':checked')) {
          $("#new-address").show();
        } else {
          $("#new-address").hide();
          }
    });
```

```js
$('.radio').change(function(){
        if ($("#other-address").is(':checked')) {
          $("#new-address").show();
        } else {
          $("#new-address").hide();
          }
    });
```

```css
#new-address{
display:none;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6" id="addresses">
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="deco_request[address]" value="value[&quot;id&quot;]"> Some address<br>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="deco_request[address]" value="other" id="other-address"> Other Address<br>
</div>

<div id="new-address">
Hi
</div>
```